# Overriding getState in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs, overriding, state, superclass

I'm making a custom stateProvider and I want to save some extra stuff for my panels' state. I read that in order to do that, what you have to do is override the `getState()` function of your panel class but make sure to call the superclass method. I tried something like this:

```
initComponent: function () {
    Ext.apply(this, {
        getState: function() {
            this.superclass.getState.call();
            return {
                col: this.up().id,
                row: this.row,
                hidden: this.isHidden()
            };
        }
    });

    this.callParent(arguments)
}
```

but it doesn't seem to work. I'm confused as to how I must apply the superclass method...

The docs say the following about a component's `getState()` method:

*Subclasses which implement more complex state should call the superclass's implementation, and apply their state to the result if this basic state is to be saved.*

Any ideas where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. override `getState` directly on your Panel definition
2. fetch the result of the super method call and apply your changes

   ```
   Ext.define('MyPanel', {
       ...
       getState: function() {
           var result = this.callParent(arguments);
           Ext.apply(result, {
               col: this.up().id,
               row: this.row,
               hidden: this.isHidden()
           });
           return result;
       }
   })
   ```

Comment: Your solution almost fixed my problem. Everything works right now except for the first time when a panel is created but its state record on the database is still empty. In order for the record to be correctly formated, a newly created panel has to have both its width/collapse changed AND its position (custom state stuff). I guess that is in order to have both getState functions called and save something? If I for example only change its position (custom state stuff) the state record in the DB doesn't get saved correctly.

Comment: what do you mean with 'doesn't get saved correctly' ? you could inser a `console.log(result)` befor the return to see what is in the panel state

Comment: I solved the problem. Essentially the panels save a new state only if something changes from their original configurations. That means that a state gets saved correctly only if the width/height or collapse status of a panel changes from its default state. Otherwise it saves an empty state `o%3A`. What I did to solve this is, in the boxready event I collapse and expand the panel programmatically. This forces the state to get saved again with all the parameters this time since there has been a change from the default values. If I didnt do that it loaded an empty state and couldnt Ext.create it.